# vim search with bracket symbols

Tags: vim

String:

```
abc|c|xyz
```

Pattern:

```
|[^|]*
```

I hope this will only match '|xyz', but it matches '|c|xzy'. Why is it that? My pattern means that "start with '|' and any following character can't be '|'". Right?

Comment: `:match Foo /|[^|]*` matches both `|c` and `|xyz`. Since they are one after the other, they appear like *one* match but they are actually *two*. If you do `/|[^|]*`, the cursor will be positioned on the `|` in `|c` (the first match) and pressing `n` will put you on the `|` in `|xyz` (the second match).

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim isn't matching "|c|xzy"  There are two separate matches, "|c" and "|xyz".  You can verify this by pressing <kbd>n</kbd> to jump between them.

It seems you only want the last match. You can add "$" to ensure your pattern only matches the end of a line:

```
|[^|]*$
```